# Switching two virtual host (configured with httpd.conf) using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost, httpd.conf, vhosts

I have configured tow virtual host for two domains www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName prod.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /data/prod/web/
     DirectoryIndex index.php
     <Directory  "/data/prod/web">
           AllowOverride All
           Allow from All
     </Directory>
     Alias /sf /data/prod/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
     <Directory "/data/prod/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
           AllowOverride All
           Allow from All
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName dev.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /data/dev/web/
     DirectoryIndex index.php
     <Directory  "/data/dev/web">
           AllowOverride All
           Allow from All
     </Directory>
     Alias /sf /data/dev/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
     <Directory "/data/dev/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
           AllowOverride All
           Allow from All
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I want with htaccess file to switch the folder pointing to the domain:

**Before**

/data/prod/web --> www.domain1.com

/data/dev/web --> www.domain2.com

**After**

/data/prod/web --> www.domain2.com

/data/dev/web --> www.domain1.com

Is it possible? could you help me ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot):

DocumentRoot Directive
Description: Directory that forms the main document tree visible from the web
Syntax: DocumentRoot directory-path
Default: DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs 
**Context: server config, virtual host**
Status: Core  Module: core

Note what's in bold here...you cannot change the DocumentRoot from .htaccess files. Here is a list of all possible context values, FYI:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/directive-dict.html#Context